# Is it possible to include a javascript file from symbolic link

Tags: javascript, php, include

I have a php web app.  I'd like to know:

- Should I place my js files in my private dir
- (if so), can/do I include from symbolic link in the public directory.

Comment: This doesn't make a whole lot of since. What "javascript files"? If you are talking about javascript to be loaded on your site they will never be kept private. You should just keep them in a convenient location. If you are using javascript on the backend then that is a whole different question. I doubt you are because you tagged php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't any harm in placing your js in a public directory, since js will still be loaded by the browser in its entirety. Js gets loaded in the dom and can be viewed easily by firebug or any javascript inspector. If you still want to, then you can put it in a private directory, and call it using php.
For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $locationOfJS; ?>"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. I just started using js/ajax with php, so I'm new at it. I run everything thru one index file and I'm paranoid about anything on the public side.

Comment: Javascript should only be used to modify client side behavior such as adding a loading icon after a Submit button is clicked, or to send the data of a form to a php file. PHP is the real server side processing that should process any private information. Now, this would be different if you were talking about nodejs, but we're not soooooo!

Comment: I like to add  time stamp to the end of my javascript files during development to force reloads of the file  <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $locationOfJS."?".time(); ?>"></script>